# Example, is this strategy pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

As the topic say by itself, is this example of strategy pattern in Javascript?

(I think question is more suitable for codereview but they redirect me on stackoverflow)

```
var canvas = {
    context:  document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
function Square(_strategy) {
    this.x = 50;
    this.y = 50;
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 100;

    this.strategy = _strategy;
}

Square.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.strategy(this);
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
function Circle(strategy) {
    Square.call(this, strategy);

    this.radius = 25;
}

Circle.prototype = new Square();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
function drawSquare(shape) {
    canvas.context.strokeRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, shape.height);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
function drawCircle(shape) {
    canvas.context.beginPath();
    canvas.context.arc(shape.x , shape.y, shape.radius, 0, 360, false);
    canvas.context.stroke();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
var shapes = [];
shapes.push(new Square(drawSquare));
shapes.push(new Circle(drawCircle));

for(var i=0; i<shapes.length; i++) {
    shapes[i].draw();
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eZAyoyI/1/watch?html,js,output)

I know that i don't need width and height for drawing circle. (I will need them later for selecting that circle, so it is not mistake :) )

Comment: If you down-voting please leave at least explanation why...

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but this question shows no effort and does not demonstrate any understanding of subject.  You've basically posted a wall of code and said: "_true or false, this uses pattern X_".

Comment: I think it is not "wall" of code, example is simply enough to be reviewed for few minutes. Anyway, thanks on suggestion.

Comment: You're right: "_Wall of code_" was a bit harsh.  Like I said, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Did you read the tooltip that goes with downvotes? it starts with "this question does not show any research effort". Well, would you argue that this question does show any research effort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but such pattern can be implemented so trivially in Javascript that it's probably not even a pattern.

Basically even if you had it like this:

```
function Square() {
    this.x = 50;
    this.y = 50;
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 100;
}

Square.prototype.draw = function(canvas) {
    canvas.context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};
```

You can just do:

```
var a = new Square();
a.draw = function(canvas) {
    canvas.context.strokeRect(this.x + 5, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};
```

Btw, do not make your classes refer to global variables. Take it as property or parameter.